# How do I convert a variable of more than 2 vectors into a dummy variable?

Tags: r

Right now I am trying to create a new dummy variable in a dataset out of a variable that has more than two vectors. More specifically, my dataset has a "State" variable, and I want to make a dummy where 1 = states in the North, and 0 = all other states. Here's a portion of the dataset (it's an extremely large set so I'll only include the essential data):

> ```
>   Year     StateICP  
> 1 1940        71     
> 2 1940        21     
> 3 1940        22     
> 4 1940        32     
> 5 1940        18     
> 6 1940        22  
> 7 1940        45     
> 8 1940        40     
> 9 1940        33
> ```

So what I would want to do is create a new Column (called "North") where if the StateICP = 21, 22, 40, or 45, then the new variable would = 1, and otherwise would be 0. Like I said, this is a very large dataset (over 1000000 observations), so I can't enter it row by row manually. I tried an ifelse function, but that only gave me errors.

I'm sure this isn't that complicated, but I am fairly new to R. I know how to create a dummy variable normally, but I am getting stuck here. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Did your `ifelse` look something like: `ifelse(yourDF$StateICP %in% c(21, 22, 40, 45), 1, 0)`?

Answer (score 2):

So, creating simple dataset to replicate what you have above:

```
df <- data.frame(Year = rep(1940,500), StateICP = sample(1:100, 500, TRUE))
```

This will create a data.frame with columns like you describe and 500 records. The StateICP values are randomly generated integers between 1 and 100. If we want to code a boolean we could simply add a new column:

```
df$boolean <- df$StateICP %in% c(21, 22, 40, 45)
```

If we want to code them specifically as 0,1 as you describe then you can use ifelse:

```
df$dummy <- ifelse(df$StateICP %in% c(21, 22, 40, 45), 1, 0)
```

You have to make sure you are using a vector in the ifelse (since it does not accept a data argument).

Comment: no need for `ifelse`, you can just do `as.integer(df$StateICP %in% c(21, 22, 40, 45))`

Comment: Yeah, I include it mostly in case somebody else has the same question and wants to use actual labels e.g. "north" and "south" but I take your point.

Comment: in that case, you could (as an alternative) also do `c('out','in')[1 + (df$StateICP %in% c(21, 22, 40, 45))]`, which is considerably faster

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I never thought of doing it that way. Thanks.